# How to run a sub at set intervals in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a UserForm in which I have to run a sub every 5 seconds. 
I know that I could use `Application.Ontime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "my_Procedure"`, but it seems to work only with macros. When I try it with a sub, I get the message:

> Cannot run the macro ''xx\xx\WorkBook1.xlsm'!my_Procedure'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

I'm an absolute beginner in Excel and VBA. I googled a lot but all answers seem to show how to repeat a **macro** every x seconds. How can I repeat a **sub** every x seconds?

Comment: Where is your "my_Prodecure" located? Is it a Private or Public Sub?

Comment: @TomaszPaluch It is located in the UserForm, and the `Application.Ontime` statement is in UserForm1.Activate(). It is a Public Sub.

Comment: Try move `my_Procedure` to module.

Comment: @Light That worked, thanks.